How to make a View that has special shape in React Native
I'm creating cards like below, the background of the card is blue, and then there's a another view on top of it that has white background and it's top right corner is some concave shape and exposes more blue background as you can see in the below screenshot. The View component itself wouldn't support this shape, what's the best way to implement this?


It's easy with svg lib, full code below

import Svg, { Path } from "react-native-svg"

const BORDER_RADIUS = 20
const CURVE_RADIUS = 20

export default SVGBackground = ({ height, width }) => {
  return (
    <Svg height={height} width={width} viewBox={`0 0 ${width} ${height}`}>
      <Path
        d={`
      M ${BORDER_RADIUS} 0
      H ${width - 120}
      
      Q ${width - 100} 0, ${width - 85} ${CURVE_RADIUS}
      Q ${width - 70} ${CURVE_RADIUS * 2}, ${width - 55} ${CURVE_RADIUS * 2}

      H ${width - BORDER_RADIUS}
      A ${BORDER_RADIUS} ${BORDER_RADIUS} 0 0 1 ${width - 0} ${
          CURVE_RADIUS * 2 + BORDER_RADIUS
        }

      
      V ${height}
      H 0
      V ${BORDER_RADIUS}
      A ${BORDER_RADIUS} ${BORDER_RADIUS} 0 0 1 ${BORDER_RADIUS} 0
      Z
    `}
        fill="white"
      />
    </Svg>
  )
}

